# Perl regular expressions troubles

Tags: regex, perl, xml-twig

I have a variable `$rowref->[5]` which contains the string:

```
"  1.72.1.13.3.5  (ISU)"
```

I am using `XML::Twig` to build modify an XML file and this variable contains the information for the version number of something. So I want to get rid of the whitespaces and the (ISU). I tried to use a substitution and `XML::Twig` to set the attribute:

```
$artifact->set_att(version=> $rowref->[5] =~ s/([^0-9\.])//g)
```

Interestingly what I got in my output was

```
<artifact [...] version="9"/>
```

I don't understand what I am doing wrong. I checked with a [regular expression tester](http://regexr.com/) and it seems fine. Can somebody spot my error?

Comment: you probably want `0-9` instead of `1-9`

Comment: That is true, I'll change the in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The return value of `s///` is *the number of substitutions it made*, which in your case is 9. If you are using at least perl 5.14, add the `r` flag to the substitution:

> If the "/r" (non-destructive) option is used then it runs the
>   substitution on a copy of the string and instead of returning the
>   number of substitutions, it returns the copy whether or not a
>   substitution occurred. The original string is never changed when
>   "/r" is used. The copy will always be a plain string, even if the
>   input is an object or a tied variable.

Otherwise, go through a temporary variable like this:

```
my $version = $rowref->[5];
$version =~ s/([^0-9\.])//g;
$artifact->set_att(version => $version);
```

Comment: I have to use 5.12 so your solution is perfect. Thanks!

Comment: change regex to match answer `0-9` instead of `1-9`

Answer (score 1):

The regex substitution changes the varialbe in place but returns the number of substitutions it made (`1` without the `/g` modifier, if it was succesful).

```
my $str = 'words 123';
my $ret = $str =~ s/\d/numbers/g;
say "Got $ret. String is now: $str";
```

You can do the substitution first, `$rowref->[5] =~ s/...//;`, and then use the changed variable.